# Sequence-to-Sequence RNN predicting Multiple Timesteps of Multiple Features

Tags: keras, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I've looked through the other "RNN model and data shape" questions on here but none of them handled this many dimensions.

Basically the question is whether or not the output_timesteps idea below is incorrect, and if so, is the only way to predict multiple features, each with multiple forecast horizons / timesteps, by having each "feature * timestep" combination be its own output neuron in the model?

I'm using Python and Keras but this question is more generally about dimensionality and model architecture so answers in any code, or without code, are helpful.

I'll build up to the case I'm asking about starting with the simplest example, to make sure we're on the same page about the simpler examples.

For all examples:

- Input data is 5 daily timesteps (t=0,...,t=4) for two features (rainfall in mm, and UV index)
- We will predict two features (number of sunscreen bottles purchased, and number of chocolate bars purchased)
- Batch size = 32
- The model will just have one SimpleRNN layer, and whatever final layer is needed to make the predictions possible (defaulting to a Dense layer if it will work with the example)

Examples:

- Sequence-to-Vector model, predict 1 timestep (t=5)

  - `return_sequences=False` so that, only after all 5 input timesteps have passed through the model, will the model compare the output predictions to the labels.
  - Label data is of size `[batch_size, features]` = `[32, 2]`
- Sequence-to-Sequence, predict 1 timestep (t=5)

  - `return_sequence=True` so that, each time a timestep of a single instance in the batch flows through the model, the two feature predictions for t=5 are compared with the label data.
  - Label data is of size `[batch_size, input_timesteps, features]` = `[32, 5, 2]`, corresponding to the 5 timesteps of input data that will each need a vector of labels for comparison.
- Sequence-to-Vector model, predict 3 timesteps (t=5, 6, 7)

  - Again, `return_sequence=False` and the above explanation holds.
  - Label data is:

    - Maybe of size `[batchsize`*`,`* **`output_timesteps`**`, features]` = `[32, 3, 2]`
    - Maybe of size `[batch_size, features]` = `[32, 6]` where the six features are the 2 features at each of the three forecast horizons
- Sequence-to-Sequence, predict 3 timesteps (t=5, 6, 7)

  - Again, `return_sequence=True` and the above explanation holds.
  - Label data is:

    - Maybe of size `[batchsize, input_timesteps,` **`output_timesteps,`** `features]` = `[32, 5, 3, 2]`, because for each input timestep, the model will have two features to compare, and 3 forecast horizons / output timesteps.
    - Maybe of size `[batch_size, input_timesteps, features]` = `[32, 5, 6]` where the six features are the 2 features at each of the three forecast horizons

My confusion comes from the "Forecasting Using a Sequence-to-Sequence Model" part of Geron's Hands-On Machine Learning book, which seems to treat the output_timesteps as a window of data instead of output features. The example only uses one feature so its unclear how multiple prediction features with multiple timesteps would be handled.

Thank you in advance!